# I want to write the same subqueries proc SQL to SAS code help me out

Tags: sas, proc

```
proc sql;
create table new as
select empid, name, salary, depno
from one
where  depno in(10,20) and 
salary<any
(select salary from one
where depno=30);
quit;
```

After running this code I got salary of depno(10,20) whose salary is less then the max salary of depno 30. So I want a a same program  in sas base means without proc sql. Can anybody help me in finding?

data sample

```
empid name salary depno
    7369:SMITH:800.00:20
    7499:ALLEN:1600.00:30
    7521:WARD:1250.00:30
    7566:JONES:2975.00:20
    7654:MARTIN:1250.00:30
    7698:BLAKE:2850.00:30
    7782:CLARK:2450.00:10
    7788:SCOTT:3000.00:20
    7839:KING:5000.00:10
    7844:TURNER::1500.00:30
    7876:ADAMS:1100.00:20
    7900:JAMES::950.00:30
    7902:FORD:3000.00:20
    7934:MILLER:1300.00:10
    7369:SMITH:80s.00:20
```

Comment: Please include an example of what you've tried so far as well as a small subset of your data for reproducibility.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this in two data steps.  Try the following:

the first data step pulls out max salary for depno(30) and places it the macro variable &max30;

the second data step pulls out the records you're interested in.

```
data _null_;
set one;
retain max30;
if (_n_ = 1) then max30 = -999999999;
if (depno = 30 and salary > max30) then max30 = salary;
call symput("max30",max30);
end;

data new;
set one;
if ( (depno = 10 or depno = 20) and salary < &max30) then output;
run;
```